# Python 3.6 Django 2.1 Creating model in CBV and URL changes

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am running python 3.6.x and django 2.1.  I am using the `allauth` module as well but am not using the social media aspects at this time.

I have a url puzzle.  I have a CBV for a model.  The "create" portion looks like:

```
@method_decorator(verified_email_required, name='dispatch')
class Create(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'Members/profile.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = 'Members/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'profileForm': self.form_class(),
            'profileState': "create"
        })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = self.request.user
            profile.save()

            my_render = render(request, self.success_url, {
                'profile': profile,
                'profileState': "display"
            })
        else:
            #
            # form has issues. send it back to the create form to fix.
            my_render = render(request, self.template_name, {
                'profileForm': form,
                'profileState': "editForCreate"
            })

        return my_render
```

As far as I can tell this is working as written.  I have the basic django `User` object that is created after email verification.  As per the AllAuth module, after a new User is verified a login is required and the new User process redirects to the creation of a new `Profile`.  A Profile form is displayed and after filling it out and submitting the user is redirected to the "index" page.

Ok, all that works.  I am sitting on the index page (the `success_url` above).  but the URL in the browser bar is still `.../Profile/create`.  I only just noticed this because I changed a CSS item and tried to refres what I *thought* was the index page but was really an attempt to re-create the profile.

Are my `render()` calls incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HttpResponseRedirect` after successful save operation rather than `render` method. And, update `success_url` to appropriate url for the index page.

**Example**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

@method_decorator(verified_email_required, name='dispatch')
class Create(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'Members/profile.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    # update the `success_url` to the index page
    success_url = 'Members/index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'profileForm': self.form_class(),
            'profileState': "create"
        })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = self.request.user
            profile.save()

            # use `HttpResponseRedirect`
            my_render = HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            #
            # form has issues. send it back to the create form to fix.
            my_render = render(request, self.template_name, {
                'profileForm': form,
                'profileState': "editForCreate"
            })

        return my_render
```